# C# Add items to a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to read values from a console application to add them to a two-dimensional array.

**Current code:**

```
public void getUserResponses(int amount)
{
    int current = 0;

    string[,] userArray = new string[amount, 2]; // Array

    while (current < amount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter username #" + current);
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        // Add username to array
        current++;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, I want to read the username and then add it to the array.

**Example:**

Read the username

```
string username = Console.ReadLine();
```

And then add the username to the array in the following format:

```
userArray[username][placeholder]
```

How could I manage this?

Comment: why do you have 2nd dimension in your array?

Comment: consider using a data structure and/or a dictionary.

Comment: Gonna add two values to the array, the second one isnt created yet but ill need it later on.

Comment: @user7347727 - if you need 2 values, consider using a `List<Tuple<T1, T2>>` instead of a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat nice readable Item1 and Item2

Comment: You can use a List<string>() and then at the very end of your iteration output the list to an array. `string[] usernames = listName.ToArray();`

Comment: if you give him generics, at least show him how to use them...

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - it was an example, which is a better solution than using a 2D array.  Obviously you can create your own class to represent the parts of the tuple, and that would be even better.

Answer (score 3):

You can access a two dimensional array by doing `array[i,j] = value;`

From what your describing it feels like a `Dictionary<string, string>` might be more relevant. It will allow you to map strings with keys (the name in your case)